# OpenCV - cvQueryFrame + avi file issue

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, avi

I'm getting some trouble while opening a no compression **avi file** on Visual Studio 2012 with OpenCV 2.4.5 (I've tried 2.4.2 to 2.4.8 versions) and it give me the following error,

```
video file c:\ ... \30-1.avi warning: Error opening file (../../modules/highgui/src/cap_ffmepeg_impl.hpp:529) Not able to video file open.
```

Someone know what to do to fix this issue?

Thanks!!

Comment: Please post the code snippet where the error is occuring.

Comment: You are most likely missing a ffmpeg codec

Comment: How to install ffmpeg codec? Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue I have been facing recently. What worked for me is copying the **ffmpeg** related DLL to the application folder. Depending on your configuration, you need to copy **opencv_ffmpeg245d.dll** for debug or **opencv_ffmpeg245.dll** for release.

**Let me know if that works for you!**

Best regards, Andrei C.